# Adding extra arguments to Haskell functions before compiling

Tags: parsing, haskell, preprocessor, metaprogramming

As part of a program which dynamically loads user inputted strings as Haskell source code, I want to do some pre-processing on the user's input before compiling it.

One of the things I would like to be able to do is to search the source for particular function occurrences and add an extra argument to them. So, for example , I might want all occurrences of :

```
addThreeNumbers 3 5
```

To become:

```
addThreeNumbers 3 5 10
```

What is the best way of accomplishing such behavior? Is it complicated enough to warrant manipulating some sort of abstract syntax tree with functions in the GHC API / Template Haskell? Or is this something simple that can be accomplished with some sort of Haskell pre-processing / parsing library? If so, what libraries and resources would you recommend?

Comment: Which functions need the extra argument? What does it depend on? Type? Name?

Comment: Just to give the simplest thing possible to start discussion rolling... how about renaming your code's `addThreeNumbers` to `addThreeNumbersInternal` and defining `addThreeNumbers x y = addThreeNumbersInternal x y 10`?

Comment: @AndrewC It would depend purely on the name at this point. So, for example, I would want to say "find all occurences of the 'addThreeNumbers' functions and add an extra argument with the value of 10 to them"

Comment: @Daniel Wagner this does indeed seem to work for simple cases but I'm imagining situations where:
1. I might feasibly need to add in arguments with values based on information outside of the user's inputted code (For example, a time stamp of an outside action, or the line numbers that the function has appeared on)

2. It would be easy to alter. Say for instance that tomorrow I decide I actually want to add two arguments to all occurences of addThreeNumbers, or that Id rather search for a different function by name

Comment: @CraigInnes You could combine Daniel's suggestion and use template haskell to do whatever IO actions you need to get that external information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghc 7.6 [qualified imports](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#package-imports), ghc-pkg hide, and ghc's -package option allow you to seamlessly add a layer between the importing file and the imported file.

Example:

Create a package with your own Data.Char, with standard .cabal file and cabal install.

```
{-# language PackageImports #-}                                                  

module Data.Char (                                                               
      toUpper                                                                    
    , Char                                                                       

    , String                                                                     
    -- ...  Export every else from "Base" Data char because the limitation of
    --     the current export facility you can not use
    --     module Data.Char hiding (toUpper)
    ) where                                                                      

import "base" Data.Char hiding (toUpper)                                         
import qualified "base" Data.Char as OldChar                                     

toUpper :: Char -> IO Char                                                       
toUpper c = do                                                                   
    print "Oh Yeahhhhhhhhh"                                                      
    return $ OldChar.toUpper c
```

Hide the base package `ghc-pkg hide base` -- this hides many  modules in this case an you need to wrap all of them if you need them.

```
> ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude --  We need language flag because the Prelude is in
                           -- base and I did not make a wrapped Prelude
ghci> import Data.Char
ghci> toUpper 'c'  -- The wrapped function
"Oh Yeahhhhhhhhh"
'C'
ghci> isSpace ' '  -- The unwrapped normal Data.Char function
True
```

Now you can use template Haskell to wrap your functions and call any IO action you need to get external information. The Users do not even need to change any of their function calls or module imports with some variation of adding 'internal' to their name.

Being able to wrap module interfaces seamlessly also means you can change the implantation of a imported module without touching the package/module code or the existing code base you are working with either; you only have to make a middle layer.

Edit response to question:

Sure you can the ghc-api lets you do all of that, but is considerably more complex, fewer examples then I would like are floating around and I seem to see more people having a hard time with it then success stories.

- For evaluation of code [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint)
- [pluggins](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins) is suggested for dynamic loading of modules
- haskell-src-ext suggested for parsing and changing code.  This is what [stylish-haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stylish-haskell) uses to do small modification to code and is your best bet.  It reportedly covers most(all?) of Haskell 2010, and many but not all GHC extensions and is probably your best bet if you do not like the first solution I provided.

The GHC-API is the only one fully compatibly with GHC compatible code as far as I know but is considerably more complex, less well documented, and more likely to change from GHC version to GHC version, or at least there is no promise it will be the same, from my limited experience. I suggested putting a module in the middle because it seemed like the quickest to get working with good test coverage, took the least amount of new knowledge and fulfilled the requirements that I picked out of your question.

Comment: Thanks, this is fairly useful. However, Is there an even more general method I could use. What would be great is if there was some way to parse some haskell source, make arbitrary changes to the parse tree (for example, adding an extra argument to functions with a particular name) then converting this modified parse tree back into haskell source